# Passing values using python and flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm quite new to python and flask. Basically I'm building a very basic web app that allows an admin to add/edit/delete a list of users. The list is display at the main menu and the admin can add/edit/delete first time around. However when I try to add/edit/delete a second time it doesn't work, also it fails if I redirect back to the main menu (where the list of users are) after an add/edit/delete. Any idea's what could be the issue?

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, render_template, redirect;
from app import app;
import pypyodbc;

myConnection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                                'Server=local'
                                'Database=All;'
                                'uid=sa;pwd=23232')
myCursor = myConnection.cursor()
myCursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
rows = myCursor.fetchall();

for r in rows:
    print(r)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    """Renders a sample page."""
    createLink = "<a href='" + url_for("display") + "'>Admin</a>";
    createLink2 = "<a href='" + url_for("user") + "'>User login</a>";
    createLink3 = "<a href='" + url_for("delete") + "'>Delete</a>";
    createLink4 = "<a href='" + url_for("edit") + "'>Edit</a>";
    return """<html>
                    <head>
                        <title>First page</title>
                    </head>
                        <body>
                            <h1>Menu</h1>
                            <div>
                            """ + createLink + """
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            """ + createLink2 + """
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            """ + createLink3 + """
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            """ + createLink4 + """
                            </div>
                        </body>
              </html>"""
@app.route('/display', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def display():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        myCursor = myConnection.cursor()
        myCursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
        rows = [dict(id=row[0], name=row[1], email=row[2], password=row[3]) for row in myCursor.fetchall()]
        return render_template('DisplayAll.html', rows = rows)
    else:
        return"<h2>Error</h2>"

@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('Add.html');
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['AddName'];
        email = request.form['AddEmail'];
        password = request.form['AddPassword'];

        SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO Users "
                  "(Name, Email, Pword) "
                  "VALUES (?,?,?)")
        values = [name, email, password]

        myCursor.execute(SQLCommand,values)
        myConnection.commit();
        #print("works")
        #myCursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
        #rows = [dict(id=row[0], name=row[1], email=row[2], password=row[3]) for row in myCursor.fetchall()]
        myConnection.close();
        return ridirect(url_for('display'));

    else:
        return "<h2>Error</h2>";

@app.route('/delete', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('Delete.html');
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            DeleteId = request.form['DeleteId'];

            SQLCommand = ("DELETE FROM Users "
                      "WHERE UsererId = "
                      + DeleteId)

            myCursor.execute(SQLCommand)
            myConnection.commit();
            #myCursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
            #rows = [dict(id=row[0], name=row[1], email=row[2], password=row[3]) for row in myCursor.fetchall()]
            myConnection.close();
            #return render_template("DisplayAll.html", rows = rows);
            return redirect(url_for('display'));
        except:
            return "<h2>Doesn't work</h2>"

    else:
        return "<h2>Error</h2>";

@app.route('/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('Edit.html');
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            Name = request.form['EditName'];
            Email = request.form['EditEmail'];
            Password = request.form['EditPassword'];
            EditId = request.form['EditId'];

            SQLCommand = ("UPDATE Users "
                      "SET Name = '" + Name +
                      "', Email = '" + Email +
                      "', Pword = '" + Password +
                      "' WHERE UsererId = "
                      + EditId)

            myCursor.execute(SQLCommand)
            myConnection.commit();
            #print("works")
            #myCursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Users')
            #rows = [dict(id=row[0], name=row[1], email=row[2], password=row[3]) for row in myCursor.fetchall()]
            myConnection.close();
            #return render_template("DisplayAll.html", rows = rows);
            return redirect(url_for('display'));
        except:
            return "<h2>Doesn't work</h2>"

    else:
        return "<h2>Error</h2>";
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have a typo in add() function.
This line:

```
return ridirect(url_for('display'));
```

should be

```
return redirect(url_for('display'));
```

Next, in display() you define myCursor and then you work with it. That is ok

```
myCursor = myConnection.cursor()
```

However, in functions add, delete and edit you are missing this definition, but you are still using it. You can not omit this definition, since the first one is valid only inside display() due to [variable scope](http://gettingstartedwithpython.blogspot.sk/2012/05/variable-scope.html).
Try adding this definition to other functions as well.

If that does not work, it might be because you also need to make a new connection for every request, not just at the beginning of the file. Then, each function would begin with

```
myConnection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                            'Server=local'
                            'Database=All;'
                            'uid=sa;pwd=23232')
myCursor = myConnection.cursor()
```

Please, let us know if this works for you.

Note: I have just noticed you are actually closing the connection after adding/removing/editing with `myConnection.close()`. Therefore, you definitely need to reopen the connection upon each request with the code above.

Comment: Your second proposal worked like a charm. Had to declare myConnection and myCursor for each add/edit/delete. Thank you for that! I'd vote your solution up but this is a new account unfortunately.